# java override equals() in custom class

Tags: java, list, overriding

I'm trying to Override the vertex variable equals. Currently when vertexList.contains("test") is called, the equals() declared in the vertex class isn't ran. Is there something I'm missing?

The full code can be found on my [git hub](https://github.com/monoxide7/p3/blob/master/Data.java) if you think it's something else, along with a quick test file UI.java. Otherwise I'm out of ideas.
Thanks,

```
class Data implements Graph
{
    java.util.LinkedList<vertex> vertexList = new java.util.LinkedList<vertex>();

    class vertex
    {
        String ID;
        java.util.LinkedList<String> links = new java.util.LinkedList<String>();
        boolean tracker = false;

        public vertex(String it)
        {
            ID = it;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj)
        {
            if (obj.equals(null))
                return false;
            System.err.println("OBJECT CHECK");
            String str = (String) obj;
            // return true; //To test if it's being accessed
            return str.equals(ID);
        }

        public String toString()
        {
            return ID;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you forget to extend the vertex class?  I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here??  You can't override a method if you are not extending/implementing a parent class.

Comment: Maybe, does vertex need to extend object?
Tested, java includes it for you.

Comment: It already does extend object

Comment: Do you reall want to have Vertex objects be equal only to String objects?  In fact v.equals(123) won't just return false; it will throw a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Why are you using `System.err` when you are printing `"OBJECT CHECK"`? Are you sure you're looking in the right place to see that output?

Comment: Eric right now I've only tested it with strings. When I get strings to work, I'll implement it ints as well.  
Rob I have it set so Syster.err shows up as red. Both are output to terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing `vertexList.contains("test")` will execute the `equals()` method of `String` against your object. You're looking for `linkedList.contains(new Vertex("a"));` which will execute **your** `equals()` method against a target object. Here's the linkedlist impl for `contains()` where `o` is the object being searched for.

```
        for (Entry e = header.next; e != header; e = e.next) {
            if (o.equals(e.element))
                return index;
            index++;
        }
```

You should also be checking for a `Vertex` instead of a `String` in the `equals()` method. That is what it is meant for. You should be trying to check if one `Vertex` equals another.

Comment: Genius! It was using the String.equals(). I changed it to vertexList.contains(new vertex("test")) and also changed the equals() method to compare the ID's of both vertexs.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish in this line?

```
String str = (String) obj;
```

If I understood the purpose of your code correctly, I think your equals method should look more like this:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj){
if( obj != null && obj.getClass().equals(this.getClass()){
    return ((vertex)obj).toString().equals(this.ID)
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```